# Does the existence of a matroid structure imply that the greedy algorithm is optimal?

Tags: algorithms, greedy-algorithms, matroids

I was going through the topic of matroid structures for the problems like Activity selection ,minimum spanning tree. I also came to know how to solve if a problem exhibits matroid structure. The statement says that problems that have matroid structure will have a greedy algorithm. But by just showing matroid structure for a problem does it mean greedy algorithm is the optimal algorithm for that problem?

Comment: The greedy algorithm solves the *maximum weight basis* problem in every matroid. If you problem is equivalent to the maximum weight basis problem in some matroid, then the corresponding greedy algorithm will solve it optimally.

Comment: See for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Greedy_algorithm).